# Display List<string> in @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TeamMember, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

Suppose now instead of `TeamMember` which is a `string`, we want to display 'TeamMembers' which is a `List<string>`, known to have a count of 3, inside the same disabled TextBoxFor, as follows:

```
John Doe, Jane Doe, Tom Thumn
```

How might this be done?

Comment: You want to display it where ? in a single input field ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.Thank you!

Comment: Are you using ViewModel's aproach?

Comment: Add a `string` property to your model that concatenates the values in the list.  Then bind the test box to that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work too.

**Controller:**

```
var model = new ModelName
{
    TeamMembers = String.Join(", ",ListItems);
};
return View(model);
```

**And in your view:**

```
@model path.to.your.model.ModelName

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TeamMembers, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

**In your model:**

```
public class ModelName
{
     public string TeamMember { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: String concatenation in a loop is a garbage collection disaster waiting to happen. Just use `String.Join()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Join` method to concatenate items in the string list.

```
<input name="MyInputName" value="@String.Join(",",Model.TeamMembers)"/>
```

Comment: Sure, but is it possible to do this while keeping the same razor syntax and using the TextBoxFor?

Comment: TextBoxFor takes a property name and generate the input for that while using the value of the property to set the value of the generated input. Why not do the string.join in server and set the concatenated string in your string property ?

Comment: better would be to use multiselect dropdown

Comment: @CaseyCrookston See my answer for that.